# Delete Up One Level in PHP

Tags: php, file, unlink

What I am trying to do is delete up one level in a new folder in PHP.

I hear the function I want to use is 'unlink'. I'm not 100% whether I am using this correctly. The script I am editing is in /includes/scriptname.php, and im trying to get it to remove an image in: /images/products/example.jpg.

Would I be doing this correctly if I did this?

```
    unlink('../images/products/' . $filename);
```

or would this be incorrect? Any replies will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

../images/products/' . $filename is correct (Note that its '..' not '.'). As long as you refer to the parent directory with '..' you can operate on anything in there.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unlink is the right tool to remove this file from the folder, yes?

Comment: yes unlink correct for files, if you want to do folders use rmdir.